# Adding/Incrementing data from a text file

Tags: php, arrays, checkbox

I have a php file that contains some data when checked displays the checked data. How do I increment the variable    "$visit" every time it is visited and save it to the text file?

new.php

```
<html> 
<body bgcolor="#99FF00">
<table border="1">
<FORM ACTION="new.php" METHOD="POST">
Enter maximum price <input type="text" name="maximumprice"/> 
<p><input type="submit" value="Go" name="Go"/>
</form>

<?

$mPrice = $_POST['maximumprice'];
$file1 = "properties.txt";
$filedata = fopen ($file1, "r");
$array1 = file ($file1); 

print "<form action=\"visit.php\" method=\"POST\">";




for ($counter1 = 0; $counter1 < count($array1); $counter1++) 
{
$arrLine = $array1[$counter1];

$pCode = getvalue ($arrLine, 0);
$price = getvalue ($arrLine, 1);
$picture = getvalue ($arrLine, 2);
$visit = getvalue ($arrLine, 3);



if ($price < $mPrice)
{
print "<tr>";
print "<td>";

print $pCode. "<br>";
print $price. "<br>"; 
//print $picture. "<br>";
print $visit. "<br>";

print "<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"box[]\" value=\"$arrLine\" />";

print "</td>";

print "<td>";
printf("<img src='$picture' width='200' height='150'>");
print "</td>";
print "</tr>";


}
} 

print '<input type="submit" name="Visit" value="Visit"/>';

// Move the form outside the for loop
print "</form>";


fclose ($filedata); 

function getvalue ($text, $arrNo) 
{ 
$intoarray = explode (",", $text); 
return $intoarray[$arrNo]; 
} 

?> 

</table>
</body>
</html>
```

this is the second page, display.php

```
<html>
<body bgcolor="#99FF00">
<?

foreach ($_POST['box'] as $values)
{
echo "$values <hr/>";
}



?> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't know about anyone else, but I read this a few times and couldn't quite get what you were asking and what you are trying to accomplish. Can you be clearer?

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Use a database :-)

No, but really, since you are storing the entire line as the value of the checkbox, you can compare that to the line in the file and update your visit field for matching lines ...

For example, in your processing file:

```
$filename = "properties.txt";
$data     = file($filename, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);

$checked  = $_POST['box'];

foreach($data as $id => $line){
    if(in_array($line, $checked)){
        //Explode the line into parts
        $tmp = explode(',', $line);
        //Increment the visit field
        $tmp[3]++;
        //Put the updated data back in the file data array
        $data[$id] = implode(',', $tmp);
        //Unset the tmp array
        unset($tmp);
    }
}

//implode the data back into a text block
$data = implode("\n",$data);
file_put_contents($filename, $data);
```

This is untested, but should yield what you are looking for ...

As a side note, you do not have to do the `fopen` call to use the `file` function. It will open and read the file.

EDIT: Since it appears that visit is the last column in each row and without any flags, the `file` function will keep the newlines at the end of each line, I added the appropriate flag to the `file` function.